# Dropdown menu won't appear in elementor Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, dropdown, elementor

The dropdown menu in my main menu (desktop) will not work when clicking on it. The dropdown menu (mobile), which is the entire menu, won't appear at all when clicking on the hamburger menu icon. Why won't it appear?

I've already tried changing the z-index of the header using some code I got from other questions and answers. I don't know how to code so I'm not sure I did it right, and the z-index may still be an issue.

I am using Wordpress and the Elementor plugin to build my website. The theme I am using is called NeoTech, built by DeoThemes. My website is [buenavistamag.com](http://buenavistamag.com).

I just want the dropdown menus to work so my visitors can navigate my website properly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dropown menu is working but not showing. Because, you need to remove **overflow:hidden** from header element.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I'm not very good with code, though. Do you know where I'm supposed to go to remove this line of code?

Comment: you can use **overflow: visible;** instead of **overflow:hidden**.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, you have created the menu. Invoke your menu options in menu editor via Appearance>Menu tab in WP-Admin

[SampleForDropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvIxu.png)