# Submenu not displaying

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, submenu

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351258/dropdown-menu-wont-appear-in-elementor-wordpress) but I can't find my error. I have this website: https://www.arte-grafico.es/que-hacemos/diseno-grafico/ but my submenu on the main top menu doesn't work.

I tried to change the overflow to visible, but I think I haven't done it correct.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I checked on hover class menu-hover is getting applied instead of tm-mega-menu-hover when you add tm-mega-menu-hover it will work.

attached screenshots for your reference.

[image]

[image]

First screenshot is what's happening in your site, but you need to add class tm-mega-menu-hover or you need to add css for menu-hover